# What are some examples of the projection operator being used in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

In Quantum Mechanics, the projection operator is defined as $\hat{P}_\psi = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, so it acts on quantum states $|\Psi\rangle$ as
$$\hat{P}_\psi|\Psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\Psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\Psi\rangle|\psi\rangle=c|\psi\rangle$$

I see that it behaves in a similar way of the projection operation between euclidean vectors: it returns a new ket in the $|\psi\rangle$ direction whose lenght $c$ is that of the projection of $|\Psi\rangle $ onto the $|\psi\rangle$ direction.

However, what is the importance of this operator in Quantum Mechanics? What are some examples of the cases in which it is necessary to make use of it?

Comment: Do related questions already contain answers your question? Among other things, it is discussed there how measurements are described through the projection operator (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/429800/276737)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of places you can find this object to be acted on. The best way would be to open a Quantum Mechanics book on pc and search for the word *Projection* and see the section and use of the Operator.

These are few or two examples.

---

The projection operator look  like
$$\mathcal{P}=|n\rangle \langle n|$$
A very nice property of the operator is rather obvious from the interpretation of it. The operator project a part of the vector along a specific basis vector. So If I project a vector along with all the bases, I should get the vector back.
$$\sum_n\mathcal{P}_n|\psi\rangle=\sum_n |n\rangle \langle n|\psi\rangle =|\psi\rangle $$
$$\sum_n|n\rangle \langle n|=I$$

That's the crucial property and use the time to when changing basis. Whenever we need to write a vector on some basis, We insert a complete set. It's also used in a change of basis.

A nice example of optics can be found on Principle of Quantum Mechanics R. Shankar: Section 1.6 Matrix element of a linear operator.

---

In the context of the density matrix, A pure ensemble given by
$$\rho=|\alpha^{(n)}\rangle \langle \alpha^{(n)}|$$

You can represent complete polarization beam with $S_z+$ as
$$\rho=|+\rangle \langle +|$$

---

It's also used in the context of perturbation theory. Look for section 5.1 Modern Quantum Mechanics Sakurai : Formal development of perturbation expansion.